# Setting breakpoint in the file with line no is not working with pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, pytest-cov

I am trying to debug pytest with pytest  --trace,it is entering in to the debug mode where i have installed pdbpp,once entered when i set the break point to a different file
using b file:name: it is not stopping at the breakpoint which i have set on a different file at specific line number.

Can any body let me how to resolve this?